# Using tab in TeXShop for command completion, not cursor jump

Tags: texshop

Tab is the trigger key for command completion in my TeXShop. It is very useful not only for actual commands but all sorts of long words often used. However, if I try to use it to complete a word which is not on my completion list, it acts like tab, shifting the cursor and then I have to undo it. Since I need tab for command completion only, I wonder: Is there a way to make tab do nothing when the sequence of letters have no completion in my command completion file?

Comment: If that were true you'd have a harder time entering a Tab when you want one. that may not happen too often though.It's also one reason I stay with using Esc as the trigger key for Command Completion in TeXShop.

Comment: Indeed, Esc might be better. But now I got used to use it for $, which I use a lot.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean about $ but you can make a macro do what you wish. I’ve given up arguments about getting used to keystrokes. My experience is that I can change my habits rather quickly.